# Document-wide search in OneNote

Tags: onedrive, onenote

Is it possible to search all of the pages in OneNote in SkyDrive? I tried many options, but don't see a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MS help, no.

"Search is limited to the current section in OneNote Web App."